# Remove Lightboxes from Wordpress Site

Tags: php, jquery, css, wordpress, lightbox

Does anyone have an idea how to remove *all* lightboxes in wordpress? We're using Cherry Framework, but have had no success on their forums (which seem to be down half the time). I've come to the conclusion that I just need to disable the ability to click on the image - that would be enough - but cannot locate the file in which do to this.

You can see the problem at http://dev.allinsure.ca/ (bottom of page - News & Events) and http://dev.allinsure.ca/resources/

Comment: Lightbox is just javascript...de-register the script from your theme.

Comment: Great suggestion! Thought of that, just trying to figure out which javascript file it is. (a moment of learning... ideas how?)

Comment: @rnevius that would create a problem as all the images are links too, which will then open the image as a whole new page.

Comment: @WisdmLabs...that has nothing to do with Lightbox. That's a template issue, if that's not the desired outcome.

Comment: Yes it does. Please check the following,
Step 2 - Turn it on 
Add a data-lightbox attribute to any image link to activate Lightbox. For the value of the attribute, use a unique name for each image.
http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THIS WORKED...

The answer to this ended up being a combination of both answers that were provided. WisdmLabs had the brilliant idea to prevent the default in javascript. Bigal had the smart idea to target the link rel. So much thanks to these two!

1) Enqueu the script in the functions.php file...

```php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_my_script' );
    function add_my_script() {
        wp_enqueue_script(
            'remove_lightboxes', // name script 
            get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/remove_lightboxes.js', 
            array('jquery')
        );
    }
```

2) Add this code (or suitable code to target links) to javascript page.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']:has(img)").click(function(e){e.preventDefault(); return false;});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add a javascript to stop the click event for the images that have links.

Try to add this script either by enqueuing or echoing it from a plugin or your theme's function.php,

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('a:has(img)').click(function(e){e.preventDefault(); return false;});
});
```

Comment: Excellent suggestion. I'm going to look up how to do that, and let you know if it works (designer brain).

Comment: This solution works almost perfectly, but it breaks images that link to other pages (like the logo on the top-left).

Comment: You are right on that. You could use an additional selector before the "a:has(img)" to filter out the images that are inside the content area.

Answer (score 0):

It's using prettyphoto. Try unbinding click and rel attribute. Code goes in to JS.

```
$("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").unbind('click');
$("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").attr('rel', '');
```

Comment: This is the best solution so far - thanks so much! Figuring out how to remove the link from those images is going to be fun, but definitely a step in the right direction.

Comment: Ideally, you probably want to just remove the <a> tag that's surrounding your images.

If you have access to your FTP, drag your theme to your desktop and search through the whole thing for "featured-thumbnail". Open up any files that contains that word and look for where there's an <a> tag after it. You'll want to remove that (don't forget the closing </a> tag)

There would be new problems if your stylesheets were using that <a> tag though. If that's the case then you'll have to leave the <a> tags and simply just replace the href="link" with a '#' where 'link' is and remove rel="prettyPhoto".

Comment: Thanks for your input, bigal. Going through each .php file would take a heck of a long time, but the thought is good.

Comment: Well, if you're using a mac, you can use your finder and search for something in particular within your theme folder and it would filter out everything for you; leaving behind only the files that contains what you're looking for (try featured-thumbnail first).